# Use or not use back-references in child objects

Tags: hibernate, uml

I hope I can say about me that I have intermediate skills in Hibernate. I spent some months in developing web applications which using Hibernate as ORM framework. But I never ask myself why we using back-references. Is it really necessary using back references in child entity objects?

In point of view UML or OOP methodology: in model where composition is used, child object doesn't have or should have reference to his parent. Only parent knows what to do with child, when to create him or delete him. So, if I want have really composition in my POJO I should not to use a back reference, but then I can have some implementation problems.

#### My questions are:

Which advantages I have when I use back-reference and which disadvantages when not.
What is best practice? Use or not use back references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a composite control, right now, in C#.

And just added a reference to each child, to its container or parent control, because required. And have done it, before, in other progr. lang. / framework (s).

Advantages:
* "I have changed a property" / "I have execute a method, you need to know" / "I took the car without permission & crashed, and call you with the (reference) celular phone you gave me"

Disadvantages:
* One extra memory space per object

Oh, I forgot. In Windows and Unix-like O.S., each child folder has a "." reference, and a ".." reference, and a root reference ("\\" or "/"). So U.M.L, says those references, shouldn't exist ?

**Methodologies / Design Patterns / Best practices, are very good, but, don't took it as a always follow rule, for any rule there always an exception.**